# NodeJS is not able to access postgres database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My app.js file is as follows

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

var pg = require('pg');
var conString = process.env.DB; // "postgres://username:password@localhost/database";

// Routes
app.get('/api/status', function(req, res) {
  pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
    if(err) {
      return res.status(500).send('error fetching client from pool');
    }
    client.query('SELECT now() as time', [], function(err, result) {
      //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
      done();

      if(err) {
        return res.status(500).send('error running query');
      }

      return res.json({
        request_uuid: uuid.v4(),
        time: result.rows[0].time
      });
    });
  });
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.json({
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

and my Dockerfile is as follows

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN  npm install

COPY . .
```

my docker-compose file is as follows:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test123
      POSTGRES_DB: testing
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: npm start app.js
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB: 'postgres://postgres:test123@localhost:5432/testing'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

When I am checking into the container DB, I can see the user, database but my app.js file cannot fetch a value from the database.
I am routing the data in this endpoint **/api/status**
when I am accessing http://ip-address:3000 == then i am getting 404 error which I mentioned in my code.
without docker, I can easily access my output at the given endpoint.

Any help will be helpful. Thanksss

Comment: Which IP url do you call on `http://ip-address:3000` the IP of the container? Try with `http://localhost:3000` but stop the local one if is active.

Comment: ip-address of my localmachine, my container running on different IP maybe I should try this ``postgres://postgres:test123@host.docker.internal:5432/testing``

Comment: The express apps I've seen have all had an `app.listen` call. Where do you tell your app to listen on port 3000?

Comment: I have added it in /bin/www

Comment: This will not help with 404 error, but your front will not be able to connect to your database. Change your database connection from `DB: 'postgres://postgres:test123@localhost:5432/testing'` to `DB: 'postgres://postgres:test123@db:5432/testing'` As you are running docker containers, localhost refers to the container itself, not your host. You need to connecto to another container. Also add a ports section in `db` service to expose 5432 port

Comment: @usuario I already tried those things, it doesn't seems to be working

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

When you ask docker-compose to spin up your containers, it creates a virtual network where each container has it's own ip address. When you - in your web container - ask to connect to `localhost`, you're trying to connect to the web container itself and not the database container.

You can access the database container by its service name `db`. So change your docker-compose file from

```
environment:
  DB: 'postgres://postgres:test123@localhost:5432/testing'
```

to

```
environment:
  DB: 'postgres://postgres:test123@db:5432/testing'
```

Comment: No success from this.