# Nodejs To Enter Values Into postgres Database

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to enter data into a table via postgreSQL. At this point, it "works" (note the quotes), but not in the desired way. Rather than entering the supplied values, I'm getting the parameters. I'm not sure how to fix this error. The query statement

const myQuery = "INSERT INTO myTable(column1,column2,column3,column4) VALUES('||$1||','||$2||','||$3||','||$4||') RETURNING *;";

is inserting ||$1|| into column 1, ||$2|| into column 2, etc.

I've checked around, including the following links, but have not been able to find an answer.
[how to enter html data into postgres database using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72543078/how-to-enter-html-data-into-postgres-database-using-nodejs)

[NodeJS is not able to access postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68951720/nodejs-is-not-able-to-access-postgres-database)

***DISCLAIMER: Essentially a newbie to nodejs and postgresql.***

My attempt at code is as follows:

```
const pg = require('pg');
var config = {
    user: PGUSER,
    database: PGDATABASE,
    password: PGPASSWORD,
    host: PGHOST,
    port: 5432
    max: 10,
    idleTimeout: 30000, 
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    }
};
const pool = new pg.Pool(config);
async function query (q) {
    const client = await pool.connect();
    let res
    try {
        await client.query('BEGIN');
        try {
            res = await client.query(q)
            await client.query('COMMIT')
        } catch (err) {
            await client.query('ROLLBACK')
            throw err
        }
    } finally {
        client.release();
    }
    return res
};
var col_1 = "text1";
var col_2 = "text2";
var col_3 = "text3";
var col_4 = "text4";

async function main () {
    try {
        const tValues = [col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4];
        const myQuery = "INSERT INTO myTable(column1,column2,column3,column4) VALUES('||$1||','||$2||','||$3||','||$4||') RETURNING *;";
        const { rows } = await query(myQuery,tValues);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Database ' + err);
    }
};
main();
```

Please be kind. What the heck am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: why not use prepared statements see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js

Comment: Are you using node-postgres? Your snippet is similar to, but not identical, to the [examples they show](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query).

Comment: @DaveNewton - Yes, this is where the code originated.

Comment: Why using all these pipes || ? A pipe is very useful in plumbing but you almost never need them in SQL. It usually goes wrong with NULL's and of course SQL injection. Use prepared statements, check the manual how to do it.

Comment: @Solaris_Guy My point was that I'd try following the examples first.

Comment: @DaveNewton Understood. Tried these prior to posting, and still struggling.

Comment: @FrankHeikens - During my searching, I found an example using the pipes. Thanks.

Comment: Do yourself a huge favor and throw that example away and forget that it exists. It's telling how not to write code.

Comment: @FrankHeikens - Okay. But I still need to solve this problem. Can you offer any suggestions?

Comment: Check the examples @DaveNewton gave you. Your current code is kind of useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the myQuery assignment statement as follows. This now works for what is needed. Thanks all for commenting.

```
const myQuery = `INSERT INTO myTable(column1,column2,column3,column4) VALUES('${col_1}','${col_2}','${col_3}','${col_4}') RETURNING *;`;
```

Comment: Be **very** wary of doing anything SQL-related like this; it’s easy to accidentally sql-inject yourself, even if security isn’t a concern.